# destructor for hashtable separate chaining implementation c++

Tags: c++, hashtable, destructor

Hello dear stackoverflow once again I'm here for help!
The idea: I'm implementing HashTable separate chaining based on sets
The problem: The destructor of set do not really work and I have no idea why
The code of set:

```
class set {

std::list<std::string>* bucket_array;

size_t bucket_array_size;

size_t set_size;

const double max_load_factor = 3.0;

public:

// Creates an empty set
set() :
    bucket_array(new std::list<std::string>[4]),
    bucket_array_size(4),
    set_size(0)
{

}
};
```

the main problem is HERE:

```
set::~set(){
    for (size_t i=0;i<=bucket_array->size();i++){
        for(auto p = bucket_array[i].begin(); p != bucket_array[i].end(); ++p){
            bucket_array[i].erase(p);
        }
    }
    delete[] bucket_array;
```

}

Comment: What are the symptoms? Is there a reason you do not use `std::unique_ptr` and use `new [] / delete[]` instead?

Comment: the problem is that there is every time segmentation fault and basically does not work, I'm trying to implement it ,there is no particular reason, I'm just good with these things but this part drives me crazy.

Comment: Don't forget the rule of three. Otherwise you will corrupt memory if the object is ever copied or assigned

Comment: I don’t know why you have those `for` loops in the destructor. Each array element is a `std::list<std::string>` and they’ll manage their own memory. Just do `delete [] bucket_array;` to release the dynamically-allocated array and the elements will be destroyed. Note: this will also eliminate one obvious bug in the outer loop control (that `<=` should probably be `<`).

Answer (score 2):

From [list::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

So when you write

```
    for(auto p = bucket_array[i].begin(); p != bucket_array[i].end(); ++p){
        bucket_array[i].erase(p);
```

you invalidate `p` and `++p` is UB. You have to use the return value of `erase`:

```
    for(auto p = bucket_array[i].begin();
        p != bucket_array[i].end();
        p = bucket_array[i].erase(p)) { }
```

or even simpler:

```
    bucket_array[i].erase(bucket_array[i].begin(),
                          bucket_array[i].end());
```

But why do you erase all the lists manually? `delete[] bucket_array;` will do it automatically.

Even better would be to use `std::vector` and then even the `delete` becomes automatic and you wouldn't need `set::~set()` at all.